# What is "dritter Grad der Blutsverwandtschaft" (third degree/grade of blood relationship)

Tags: relationship-analysis, german-language

Just found the term "dritter Grad der Blutsverwandtschaft" in a 1793 marriage record of northern Alsace. I know that I can translate this to "third degree or grade of blood relationship", but that does not really help me. Are we talking about second cousins? third cousins?

---

Added after some reflection: The two men so identified were members of the bride's wedding party, but neither was the groom. I have not seen such identifications in any other records from the era and area. Why would they be added here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second cousins would be the "*third degree of blood relationship*". People who were related more closely than that were [not permitted to marry](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8I5aCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT104&lpg=PT104&dq=%22third%20degree%20of%20blood%20relationship%22&source=bl&ots=Abj5MDNfuP&sig=DzgZox-u_nSpxf6DEPLfO-g_UXU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCr4vrjfXaAhWFjqQKHR2YAtgQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=%22third%20degree%20of%20blood%20relationship%22&f=false) (without special dispensation).

[image: Consanguinity]

- Source - [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Table_of_Consanguinity_showing_degrees_of_relationship.png)

As the above table shows, second cousins were not the only family relationship that would qualify as *third degree of blood relationship*, but in cases like this it probably means *Second cousins*, or perhaps *Second cousins Once removed*.

The ages of the individuals (if provided) might give a better idea about the exact relationship.

Comment: Your table shows a small number 6 next to "second cousins". Does that relate to this "third degree" that you speak of? Why third and not sixth? What is the convention here?

Comment: You should look to number near great grandparents..